# Dynamically added footer doesn't stay at the bottom of page ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, footer

In a certain page of the project, I am dynamically adding panels to the form inside a loop. When the loop ends, I am dynamically adding a footer, which I want to place at the bottom of the page. The code and the CSS classes used are the following:

```
Form.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='form'></ div >" +
                                             "<div class='footer'>  +
                                                    "<p>Copyright © 2019-2020 SiteName.com™. All rights reserved.</p>" +
                                             "</div>"));

   .form {
padding-top: 50px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
text-align: center;
min-height: 84vh;
```

}

```
 .footer {
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
border: 1px dotted black;
padding: 10px;
bottom: 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 0px;
```

}

I have used the exact same code for the footer in another page, except it was not loaded dynamically, adn it worked fine, with the footer being placed at the bottom of the page. What can I do to get the same result from dynamically adding the footer?

Comment: does the content of this page is smaller....hence footer pulls up ? a screenshot would have been helpful

Comment: try   position: fixed;

Comment: no, the dynamic content created in the page in which I saw the difference is pretty much the same as the fixed content of the other page

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fixed/Sticky Footer Example</h2>
<p>The footer is placed at the bottom of the page.</p>

<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```